# Libre Office crash on openning documents

Tags: libreoffice

I have just updated my ubuntu system from 16.04 to 18.04 LTS only to find that, even with a new install of libre office (uninstalling when I first witnessed the problem of crashing on attempting to open documents), I am still getting the same problem. Every document I attempt to open either results in the libre office program crashing and shutting down or in a blank page (when I know these documents and what was in them).

These are my system specs: Sony Vaio laptop
Intel® Core™2 CPU T7200 @ 2.00GHz × 2 
Intel® 945GM x86/MMX/SSE2
GNOME 3.28.2
OS Type 32-bit
Disc 310.8 GB

I would be grateful for any solutions to this as I need the machine for work! Thank you.

Here is an error message screenshot that I got when attempting to fix broken packages within the BIOS ubuntu recovery mode settings:
[![BIOS SCREENSHOT ERROR MESSAGE][1]][1]

Here is the etc/apt/sources.list
    sabirah@zurisuri:~$ cat /etc/apt/sources.list
    # deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 12.10 *Quantal Quetzal* - Release i386 (20121017.2)]/ quantal main restricted

```
# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
```

deb http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic main restricted
deb-src http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic main restricted

```
## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
```

deb http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates main restricted
deb-src http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates main restricted

```
## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
```

deb http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic universe
deb-src http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic universe
deb http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates universe
deb-src http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates universe

```
## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu 
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to 
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in 
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
```

deb http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic multiverse
deb-src http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic multiverse
deb http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates multiverse
deb-src http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates multiverse

```
## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
```

deb http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-backports main restricted universe multiverse

deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security main restricted
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security main restricted
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security universe
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security multiverse
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security multiverse

```
## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
```

deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu bionic partner
deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu bionic partner

ALSO I TRIED: 
    sabirah@zurisuri:~$ cat/etc/apt/sources.list.d/*
    bash: cat/etc/apt/sources.list.d/*: No such file or directory
    sabirah@zurisuri:~$ /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*
    bash: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-earth.list: Permission denied

Comment: Does it only crash with your documents or with all documents in general? What happens if you open f.ex. a plain text document such as /etc/motd with it?

Comment: OK I will try that and get back to you. Thanks for your response.

Comment: OK I tried rtf files (unfortunately I don't have any text files) and same issue; white blank screen followed by message giving me option to force quit or wait.

Comment: Following advice in another thread relating to libre office in 14.04, I tried deleting the libreoffice config folder by finding it through control+H within home. It made libre office crash even faster than before so I have restored the deleted files from the deleted files folder.

Comment: If you start lilbreoffice without a document, then it doesn't ask you to wait or to force quit? What about if you open (or create, save and load) a Calc document?

Comment: If I start LibreOffice without a document, the bar gets halfway across the libre office logo and then it all crashes and disappears. If I start libre office through terminal window it does open up. However when I want to create a blank document to write, it crashes out.

Comment: LO not behaving the same when you start it from the command line or from the menu points to the start procedure not being the same. Ie. you could inspect the menu entry and see how LO is started there and you could see (`which libreoffice` or such), how LO is started from the command line. You have installed libre office with apt-get or via Ubuntus software management interface right? Could you have a look what's in /etc/apt/sources.list and /etc/apt/sources.d/* - maybe you have a mix up of different non-compatible package repositories there.

Comment: Yes I installed libre office from apt-get. Excuse my ignorance but where do I find the etc folder to look at the apt/sources.list and sources.d/* contents? Is this something I need to do via terminal window or home folder?

Comment: OK I have found how to navigate to the etc folder via "other locations" and "computer" in the home folder. I have found within etc the apt file and within that a sources.list.   I have also found the sources.list.d folder. What I do not know is how to work out which different non-compatible package repositories are there. Is it better to do this in terminal?

Comment: I have gone into BIOS to see if I can use the package fix options within the ubuntu recovery mode options. I get the following error message (I have put this within the question above).

Comment: Hi chris, so if you want to look at the `apt` sources from the terminal, then you could do: `cat /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*`. You then should get lines like `deb http://ftp.ch.debian.org/debian/ stretch main non-free contrib`. I'm using debian here, so packages are coming from there and the release I'm on is named `stretch`. You should only have lines with an Ubuntu URL there and from a single release *only*.

Comment: One other thing that came to my mind is that your computers RAM could be broken. There's a way to test your RAM at boot time using the `memtest` entry in your boot menu. I don't know if you have that, if not you should be able to google it.

Comment: The errors you are seeing in the `BIOS ubuntu recovery mode` are telling you that the system very probably can't connect to the internet (`failed to resolve...`). I do not know how Ubuntu connects to the internet when booting into `BIOS ubuntu recovery mode`, but I'm guessing that if you do not connect the computer to an ethernet cable on a network where it can get it's network settings by DHCP, then you'll need to configure that network access somehow (wireless settings, modem settings or such).

Comment: Hi Tomas, I have added the output from terminal when typing cat/etc/apt/sources.list  and then /etc/apt/sources.list.d/* to the question above underneath the screenshot from the BIOS error. I will check the RAM. When the BIOS error occurred, the computer was connected with ethernet cable to internet so I don't understand why it could not access the web.

Comment: Hi chris, you might have seen, that the `sources.list` contents are displayed in a very ugly way in the question. As is it is quite hard to see which lines are commented out and which not. When you add "code" or code like stuff in your question, then prepend 4 spaces to that text, so that it is rendered as code.

Comment: Hi Tomas, I have managed to get it less ugly by following your instructions. Thank you : O )

Comment: @chrissailor Sorry for being late to the party...but another suggestion is to create a new user account.  And then use that account to see if you can open the files.  A second suggestion is to boot with Ubuntu on a USB drive (i.e., a bootable image).  That should have libreoffice on it.  Does that work?  Of course, the other ideas (i.e., memory, internet, etc.) are worth trying...what I'm suggesting is in addition to them.

Comment: same issue https://askubuntu.com/questions/1075982/libre-offices-does-not-open-lo-documents/1075994?noredirect=1#comment1766641_1075994

Comment: Try my workaround from the link above.

Comment: Hi I tried that and it has worked! Thanks so much! Thank you to all of you who have been so patient and helped me out   : O )

Answer (score 1):

I highly suggest installing the latest LibreOffice from a snap - a snap essentially containerises the install and makes it not require any system libraries as it bundles everything you need automatically which gives it a higher chance of working properly.

Since you are on Ubuntu 18.04, it automatically comes with the snaps daemon which means you can install a LibreOffice snap by opening up the terminal and entering the following command (the classic flag means it will have full access to your files meaning you can store and open documents anywhere on your storage):

`sudo snap install libreoffice --classic`

You can then run it from the terminal with the following command to ensure you are launching the snap version of LibreOffice (you would use .writer for writer, .draw for draw, etc):

`/snap/bin/libreoffice.writer`

If this solves the crashing, then you can consider removing older versions of LibreOffice with the following command (although this is optional, you should be able to choose which version of LibreOffice is the default):

`sudo apt-get purge libreoffice*`

If you are still receiving crashing, is it possible the documents got corrupted? If they are crashing on a different PC, it is likely they are corrupted. If so, do you have a backup to restore them from?