# Libre Offices does not open LO Documents

Tags: libreoffice

Yesterday 16/9, I did an update on Libre Office as per "update" message from Ubuntu 18.04 Developer Edition  .
This morning I want to start Libre office and it does not load any existing/new documents.
You get the main LO screen and when you select your document, it blinks
....... and its closed.

LibreOffice 6.0.6.2 Build ID: 1:6.0.6-0ubuntu0.18.04.1

I have tried the following solution but it did not work:
"Deleting" the .config/libreoffice directory

Pls advise

[As per DK Bose request inxi -Sr](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EK6Uy.png)

Second edit:
I have removed my original install with help of this link:
https://anglehit.com/how-to-completely-remove-libreoffice-in-ubuntu-the-command-line-way/

and install it with this link:
http://tipsonubuntu.com/2018/08/11/install-libreoffice-6-1-ubuntu-18-04-16-04/    (the 2nd option ppa:libreoffice)

I have accepted that my new LO could break with a new update.... I need my
documents now
New version : 6.1.1.2 Build ID: 1:6.1.1~rc2-0ubuntu0.18.04.1~lo3

Comment: What is "Ubuntu 18.04 Developer Edition". A search turned up nothing.

Comment: I'll write an answer just a second

Comment: That is the version with only Firefox installation. All other user applications you need to install yourself. fyi I removed Firefox and install Iron Browser

Comment: Install `inxi` and then post the output of `inxi -Sr`.

Comment: There's a "minimal" install option but it certainly isn't generally referred to as a "Developer Edition".

Comment: @ DK Bose OK, I have updated my request with the output of inxi -Sr

Comment: LO 6.0.3 is what you would have if using the (supported) Ubuntu repositories. What source are you getting (unsupported here) 6.0.6 from? Check your logs - when did it update? It might be a simple matter of rolling back.

Comment: That is what I indicated in my answer.

Comment: @vanadium In JoKeR's mentioned the other solution. That was your solution. Maybe it was not clear enough.... The commands I had to look it up on the internet  Anyway Thanks for your help  Same to everyone who has replied

Comment: Has this been solved?

Comment: @ vanadium yes, it has been solved

Answer (score 2):

Current version supported on Ubuntu 18.04 is 6.0.3.2. You have version 6.0.6.2. Likely, therefore, you are installing it via another software source. Remove the version you installed and remove the third party software source you used in "Software & Updates, "Other software" tab. Then reinstall.

Another possibility is that you have "Pre-release updates" checked on the "Developer options" tab of "software & Updates". If yo did that, then you know you can expect that a certain update may break. If you did that by mistake, again remove your current version and uncheck the checkbox on the "Developper options" tab. Then reinstall.

Comment: That's a standard issue with Java on all Linux distros.

Comment: I'm guessing `LibreOffice 6.0.6.2 Build ID: 1:6.0.6-0ubuntu0.18.04.1` indicates a ppa.

Comment: Hi All,
I have removed my current version of LO and reinstall it again with some remarks see my original post

Answer (score 2):

I am also using the Libreoffice PPA and did an update yesterday (17/09) from 6.0.6 to 6.1.1 (6.1.1.2 Build ID: 1:6.1.1~rc2-0ubuntu0.18.04.1~lo3).
 Ran into the issue you mention wherein the UI was corrupted / blank, buttons were missing and unable to create /open any documents. I closed libreoffice, renamed the `.config/libreoffice` to `.config/libreoffice(old)`. I reopened Libreoffice and issue solved for me.

Possible reason may be incompatible config files, older config files are causing LO 6.1 UI to appear corrupted.

Answer (score 0):

Launch LO main window click ***Tools***-->***Options***-->***Advanced*** and remove a tick ***Run Java environment***

[image]

Comment: Hi JoKeR,
When I click on advanced LO main window also shutdown I will try the other solution. Thanks for help so far ....